# Available options in Spring MVC to customise the 405 error response?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

please guide me.

Stuck on 2 issues pertaining to Spring MVC -

1. In my project, whenever an exception occurs, the entire stack trace is getting printed in the response. Something like this -

> {
>       "cause": null,
>       "stackTrace": [
>           {
>               "methodName": "resolveHandlerMethod",
>               "fileName": "AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java",
>               "lineNumber": 123,
>               "className": "org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter$ServletHandlerMethodResolver",
>               "nativeMethod": false
>           }, ...

I tried to remove this issue by going through various suggestions like @ControllerAdvice and @Order(0), and even in web.xml -

```
<error-page>
    <location>/error/GeneralError</location>
</error-page>
```

As a result I am able to tap the exceptions thrown from the controllers like NPE etc, but exceptions related to HTTP URLs (that I believe happen before the controller mapping) I am not able to catch.

Like in my scenario, if the user enters a POST request in the REST client instead of an applicable GET URL, though the error reported in logs is like this -

```
Aug 09, 2018 7:05:00 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported
WARNING: Request method 'POST' not supported
```

still the @ControllerAdvice or error mapping in web.xml, is not able to catch the 405 error here and here by I don't get a chance to add my custom messages.

Any advise for me?

2. Secondly I tried to extend

> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver

, and use it with bean definition in web.xml, with @Controller and @ExceptionHandler annotations, still the Spring framework just simply ignored my effort and again went with the default one.

Can't we modify this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it to extends `DispatcherServlet`.

Try with this:

```
public class GlobalRequestHandler extends DispatcherServlet{

    @Override
    protected void service(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String path = request.getServletPath();
        //handle here as per your requirement.
        super.service(request, response);
    }
}
```

add this bean in configuration class:

```
@Bean
DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet() {
    return new GlobalRequestHandler();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but I want the behaviour of DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver to handle the exceptional or erroneous situations. Sorry I might sound noob, but isn't DispatcherServlet something that will impact my positive scenarios as well?